# XMLType from Oracle Result set is not being fected and exits application without error

Tags: java, oracle, xmltype

I have a query that creates XMLElement which gives "SYS.XMLType" as output. I tried to fetch the data using XMLType it exits when I try to cast as given on the oracle website.

```java
dppSummaryps = (OraclePreparedStatement) connDb.prepareStatement(dppSummary);
System.out.println("Prepared Statement before bind variables set:\n\t" + dppSummaryps.toString());
dppSummaryps.setString(1, readTimeStart);
dppSummaryps.setString(2, readTimeEnd);
// System.out.println("uwjdpps.dppSummary() " + dppSummaryps.toString());
ResultSet rs = dppSummaryps.executeQuery();
OracleResultSet ors = (OracleResultSet) rs;
ResultSetMetaData mdata = rs.getMetaData();

if (mdata.getColumnType(1) == OracleTypes.OPAQUE
        && mdata.getColumnTypeName(1).compareTo("SYS.XMLTYPE") == 0) {
    // we know it is an XMLtype
    System.out.println("YEAH XMLTYPE: Column name = " + mdata.getColumnTypeName(1));
}
while (ors.next()) {

    // get the XMLType
    OPAQUE poxml = ors.getOPAQUE("XML");
    XMLType xmltype = (XMLType) poxml;
    // get the XML as a string...
    System.out.println(xmltype);
    // xml = (XMLType) rs.getObject(1); 
    // dppSummaryType = rs.getString("XML");
    String result = IOUtils.toString(poxml.getStream());
    System.out.println(result);
    try {
        File targetFile = new File(FILE_PATH_XML + "test.xml");
        // OutputStream outStream = new OutputStream(targetFile);
        // outStream.write(result);

        // IOUtils.closeQuietly(outStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String err = e.toString();
        System.out.println(err);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried rs.getSQLXML("XML"); ?

Comment: Yes I treid but It crashes once it reaches to this line. It goes to finally directly without going to catch statement.

Comment: maybe a mismatch of versions of jars ojdbc, xdb, xmlparser.

Comment: Do you have any preference for all of those ?

Comment: Preference? No, you have to align the JAR version to be compatible with the server version... and the JDK you are using…  There is a page on Oracle site with a correspondance table.